# What is "domain" in kubebuilder scaffolding?

Tags: kubebuilder

The kubebuilder scaffolding command includes a repo and domain e.g.

```
kubebuilder init --domain tutorial.kubebuilder.io --repo tutorial.kubebuilder.io/project
```

I found following text in kubebuilder book about "domain":

> domain: Store the domain of the project. This information can be provided by the user when the project is generate with the init sub-command and the domain flag.
> And domain: domain for groups (default "my.domain")

I understand domain is usually to set boundaries to avoid naming conflicts e.g. different teams in a company can use different domains/sub-domains and have freedom of choosing names under that domain/sub-domain.
But in the context of a kubebuilder project:

- What name conflicts are we avoiding here ? What if teams are different but still they deploy to a shared cluster ? What if domain name itself is duplicate ? When do you figure out there's a conflict ?
- What are the functional implications of a domain e.g. on CRDs, on APIs etc. ?
- Can you change it later and any gotchas ?
- Can you have no domain at all, not even default - my.domain ?

I'm aware that these answers could be much longer for a post if elaborated, any guidance or material in this context would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The domain is the Kubernetes 'group', which as you describe is used for namespacing and avoiding naming conflicts.
A 'group' along with a 'version' and a 'kind' uniquely identify a type of resource that the Kubernetes API server knows about.

To answer your questions:

- The name conflicts you are avoiding are generally if two separate groups have a concept they want to represent with a similar name. Generally, the friendly name of a resource goes in the 'kind' field, e.g. 'Bucket'. If you have two separate concepts of a bucket, then without the existence of the 'group', you might call one `kind: AWSBucket` and the other `kind: GCPBucket`. With groups, you can do the following:

  ```
  apiVersion: aws.amazon.com/v1
  kind: Bucket
  ```

  as separate from

  ```
  apiVersion: gcp.google.com/v1
  kind: Bucket
  ```
- The previous dot-point hints at this. Functionally, the 'domain'/'group' along with the version form the `apiVersion` field of any resources you provision against the CRD, and will form the `group` field of the [Custom Resource Definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#create-a-customresourcedefinition).
- You can change it later. There's the obvious gotcha that some other team might already be using your namespace. You'll also need to update and re-deploy any resources that use this domain as part of a custom resource. Practically, this might as well be a new API from the point of view of Kubernetes. You'll start again with no resources of that kind, and so you'll need to update and re-deploy any resources you've created against the old kind. This may cause issues, though it should be possible to handle these as part of a controller (e.g. migrate any controller state recorded against the old resource to the new resource).
- No, it's not possible to not define a domain. I'm not sure what Kubebuilder will do if you don't provide this flag. But practically, `group` is a required field on the `CustomResourceDefinition` resource that is used to register the custom resource with Kubernetes. See [the API documentation for CustomResourceDefinition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/extend-resources/custom-resource-definition-v1/#CustomResourceDefinitionSpec)

Resources:

- [Kubernetes docs on API groups and versioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups-and-versioning)
- [Kubernetes docs on using API groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups)
- [Kubebuilder docs on groups, versions and kinds](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/gvks.html)